# How many increasing 3 term geometric progressions can be obtained from the sequence $1, 2, 2^2,2^3,... ..., 2^n$?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, combinations

For example, an increasing 3-term geometric progression for $n ≤ 8$ is $\{2^2, 2^5, 2^8\}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $2^a, 2^b, 2^c$ is a geometric progression if and only if $a,b,c$ is an arithmetic progression.